# How should I store usernames/password for automated authentication?

Tags: asp.net, database, security, authentication

An organization I work for has a few different websites they use on a daily basis. I've been asked to develop a web application (using ASP.NET) that can access/synthesize information from these and display it in one location. Unfortunately, one of the websites does not support OAuth or anything similar, so I need to store their login credentials in a database.

My first thought was to use their credentials for my site as a key to encrypt their credentials for the remote site. For example: Bob logs in to my website with the password hunter2. Using that password, I decrypt Bob's credentials for www.example.com and log in as Bob there. Since I don't need to access example.com unless Bob is on my site, I can discard the decrypted credentials once he's done.

My assumption that simply using hunter2 (or whatever Bob's password is) isn't enough and that there is a "standard" way that I haven't been able to find on Google or Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can you use a standard solution like Lastpass or Keypass?  This is a pretty big problem to solve and the little details are in the specific requirements and a multitude of attacks that you don't want to make yourself open to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't avoid storing the passwords on the server, then encrypting with the user's "master" password (e.g. "hunter2") is your best bet. No other approach offers protection in the event that the server is compromised. Now... how much protection you get hinges entirely on the complexity of the user's master password. I'll offer my analysis of the security of this scheme at the end, but before that, let me review the pitfalls to avoid.

First—and I assume that you already know this, but—[you must not store the user's master password anywhere](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html). Ok, with assumptions out of the way...

**Do not use the user's actual password as the key to the encryption function.**

Consider what would be possible if you did: what if an attacker managed to download your entire *users* table, complete with encrypted *example.com* passwords? We all know that user chosen passwords are easy to guess. What would stop the attacker from repeatedly decrypting the encrypted *example.com* password, trying [40 million commonly used passwords](http://www.openwall.com/passwords/wordlists/) as the key, discarding any result that doesn't look like a password (that is, the decrypted result does not appear in the wordlist)? AES is [designed to be fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set). While not an apples to apples comparison, a sense of the speed of AES should be imparted when you consider that an encrypted version of the aforementioned 500mb wordlist could be decrypted in about one second on modern hardware. Worse yet, the attacker would not only get the *example.com* password, they would also have the key used for encryption, or in other words, the user's master password!

That, in a nutshell, is why you need to use a [key derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) (KDF). A KDF will ideally protect you in three ways:

1. Require a non-trivial amount of time to compute each key. A user can wait one second for the server to turn their password into a key. An attacker *may be* less inclined to wait 40,000,000 seconds—see analysis below.
2. [Salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) the password. Without salt, an attacker could brute-force the entire *users* table in one pass, not to mention make a [space-time tradeoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-time_tradeoff).
3. Prevent recovery of the master password, even if the attacker recovers the encryption key.

One such KDF that provides all three is [PBKDF2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.2). Conveniently, there is [an implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) built in to .NET:

```
public static byte[] DeriveKey(int keyBitSize, string password, byte[] salt) {
    const int iterations = 1<<12; // Once set, any change will break decryption.
    using (var kdf = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations)) {
        return kdf.GetBytes(keyBitSize);
    }
}
```

**Analysis**

40 million seconds is less than 500 days. Since wordlists are usually ordered with the most commonly used passwords first, the attacker has a good chance of finding the password in significantly less than half the time it takes to try the entire wordlist. As a final wrinkle, it is possible to try keys in parallel: a 500-node botnet could try the entire wordlist in a day.

That's the problem with relying on the user's password for encryption security. You can choose to accept this risk or you can decide not to store the user's password on the server. If you decide to store encrypted passwords on the server, you can mitigate the risk by increasing the complexity requirements for the user's master password.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever approach you take will have issues that will leave you doubting yourself. You need to balance the solutions against your environment & see what best fits.

Will each user of your app have an account on the remote system? How are users authenticated by your system? Will your app run in a trusted environment (eg corporate network).

I wrote a similar app to front an internal system that had it's own username & passwords. My app used Windows Integrated auth to figure out who the user was. it then asked for their password to the remote system & encrypted that value using a hard-coded key & stored the value in the DB. It could then retrieve the value, decrypt it & supply it to the remote system when needed.

Now in a non-trusted environment, someone could obtain my binaries & work out what they key was & get all the passwords. That would be bad. But on a corporate network, if they did that, they should come & work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You already have access to the user's clear-text secondary passwords, so regardless of whether or not you throw away the encryption key, you're still responsible for their safety when it is in the clear. Keep that in mind when you handle the passwords.

If you use the user's own password to encrypt, you are reducing the strength of all their secondary passwords to the strength of the primary one. This is probably bad since a) user passwords are notoriously weak already (I know, why do we even bother in the first place?) and b) even with the strongest of passwords, it still won't match the strength of a solidly random 256 bit AES key.

My suggestion is to consider having a single AES key that encrypts their clear-text secondary passwords. Then, guard the AES key well. It may make sense, instead to have a root AES key that encrypts many sub-keys, one for each user. You'll have to do a risk analysis, I suppose.

Comment: Does this offer significant protection over full disk encryption? If an attacker compromises the server, what protections are in place to prevent them from grabbing the AES key from memory *and* all the encrypted passwords?

Comment: FDE that is implemented in software still requires a clear text key in memory to decrypt it, and the FDE that is implemented in hardware doesn't help in the situation because usually when the machine is on, the hard drive is unlocked and decrypted. FDE is better at protecting a hard drive from physical theft.

Comment: Regarding your second question, there is no mechanism to protect an attacker who has access to memory from reading your AES key. However, if he has access to memory, he can also access your users passwords when they get decrypted using their primary passwords. So your solution is generally just as vulnerable.

Comment: And besides: If I rob a bank, I go in, grab everything I can get immediately and run. But if I hack a server, I place things that linger so that I can continually exploit the server. Therefore, if your server is compromised to that degree, you're already finished. You should try to harden your server so you know that is unlikely to happen.

Comment: Indeed, that's all basically true. Encrypting the passwords (whether in the database or with FDE) protects them from physical theft. Encrypting the passwords with a user-supplied password *additionally* protects them from a hit-and-run attack. Real world safes are not sold as unbreakable, but sold with a guarantee of how long they can resist attack. If you don't have any way to detect and respond to attacks, keeping your valuables in a safe or using encryption this way isn't going to help. If you *can* detect attacks, encrypting with a per-user password can help limit the damage.